# Is it a bad practice to send HTML over an WebSocket connection

Tags: node.js, websocket

I am developing a small app in Node.js with a MongoDB database, I have nginx in front to handle static files and the initial index.html.

When I visit my index.html all the javascript/css/img files are loaded, and a websocket connection is made to the node.js server.

Initially my index.html is empty, it needs to be filled with the right template file. One thing I could do is do a normal ajax req.

$.get('myfile.html') and append it to my content. 
The websocket just handles the database data.

---

Now I already have an open websocket connection the server, why don't I just transfer the .html template along with the data from the database, and merge it in the client.

The template files are just little html snippets, why waste a http req, right??

---

Note that this app will only be used by selective people with full html5 browser support. No fallback situations are required.

Comment: Have you tried [Backbone.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/)?

Comment: Yes, but I did not get the sync function to work. There are some examples online, but they just look to complicated for my needs. Most of the logic I have on place already, I just want to know if the WebSocket can be used for html.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given that HTTP is so well suited for serving files, with caching -- potentially in several layers -- working for you so you won't even have to send any html content more than once to a visitor, I definitely think the upsides outweighs the downsides. It sounds like you could send an index.html along with related content, and have the templates in your index.html (e.g. as in [jQuery templates](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.template/) which can use a `<script id="fooTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">` tag).

Obviously you *can* send the templates over a WebSocket.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that is exactly what I want to do. I even already use jQuery template and it works quite well. Great!